# Dead store message for analyze on array enumeration

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray

I am using Xcode 5.0.2. When I run analyze on my project, it gives me dead store messages for the stop argument in NSArray indexOfObjectWithOptions:passingTest: . The message is - Value stored to 'stop' is never read. The sample code is

```
 NSUInteger index = [self.array indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            // Do some check. If it passes
            stop = YES; // Reports dead store here
            return isFound;
        }];
```

I believe I am stopping the enumeration correctly. Is there a another way of setting the stop value so that I can avoid this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
stop = YES;
```

to:

```
*stop = YES;
```

You need to dereference the pointer to set its value.

To be really safe though you should do this (it avoids a crash if the pointer is `nil`):

```
if (stop) {
    *stop = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Completely overlooked that it was a pointer variable. Is there any scenario in which the stop within an NSArray enumeration could actually be nil?

Comment: In this case, `stop` should never be `nil` since it's meant to be used by this standard, Apple provided method.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using that variable `stop` in any other place in your code, you are just assigning a value to it, but not using that value.

**Situation 1**:

If you write a code like:

```
- (BOOL)deadStore
{
   BOOL dead = YES;     // dead store warning
   dead = NO;
   return dead;
}
```

**Situation 2**:

If you write a code like:

```
- (int)deadStore
{
   BOOL dead   = YES;     // dead store warning
   int notDead = 7
   return notDead;
}
```